# How can i load the different xibs for single class depends on current device in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have the complete code  in view controller. So, i need to display the same output in iPad,iPhone and iPod. So, am using single view controller for processing data.For this purpose how can i select the different XIB that may ipod or ipad depends on current device in iOS?

Instead of creatimg one more view controllers i want single viewcontroller and 2 XIB's

Comment: if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        ViewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]; but i need to load only xib..how can i ?
    } else {
       viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }

Comment: Add ~ipad suffix to xib name. For example: MyViewController~ipad.xib. [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"MyViewController" ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
}
else
{
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: if your current device is iphone/ipod, initialize the controller with one .xib, otherwise initialize it with the other .xib

Comment: But i don't have the .h and.m file for iPad.i have only viewController_ipad.xib. when i use your code i get empty view with out data.

Comment: you have two different .xib files, am i right ?
in that case, open .xib, click on the file's owner object, and then in the 'identity inspector' set its class to your 'viewcontroller' class. And finally connect all the outlets, repeat this process for both the .xibs

Comment: There is not need to do this, iOS can do this for you by using the platform specifier in the name like `~ipad` or `~iphone`.

Comment: if you are initializing you viewcontroller from appdelegate, then you can check it in appdelegate, or even you can overload your viewcontroller to perform this check i-e overload the [initWithNibName: bundle:]

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple when you create a universal app, itself it will give the code check the device type and load particular xib.

for example

```
 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
```

Comment: There is not need to do this, iOS can do this for you by using the platform specifier in the name like `~ipad` or `~iphone`.

Answer (score 0):

`[UIDevice currentDevice]` will give you the details about the current device. use this in a if loop and select the xib for iphone or i pad.

```
    if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
{
 load 1 xib 
} 
else 
{ 
load another 
}
```

Comment: There is not need to do this, iOS can do this for you by using the platform specifier in the name like `~ipad` or `~iphone`.