# How can i load the different xibs for single class?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xib, viewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i load the different xibs for single class depends on current device in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373739/how-can-i-load-the-different-xibs-for-single-class-depends-on-current-device-in)

I developed one universal app.i implemented the application for iPhone .now i have to implement for iPad. i have the complete code regarding data processing is in view controller and view-controller.xib is used for iPhone. how can i use the code for iPad.

I created one xib file(ViewController_iPad.xib) for ipad.when i run the application in iPad im getting the ipad xib but the data is not displaying.

How can i get the data present in viewController?

Thanks in adv..

Comment: did you set the file owner of your new ipad xib as your class ?

Comment: Yes i did..I gave the class name as ViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS has a easy method for loading different `NIB` for iPad and iPhone.

If you name you `NIB` file like: `ViewController~ipad.xib` or `ViewController~iphone.xib` iOS will load the appropriate one.

I only add the `~ipad` view to my universal project, this the `NIB` without out any device specifier will get loaded on all other devices.

You can now just load your `UIViewController` like :

```
 [[UIViewController alloc] alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

This will also work for images:

```
back.png //Normal images
back@2x.png // Retina images
back~ipad.png // iPad normal image
back@2x~ipad.png // Retina iPad images
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this method in app delegate

```
 +(NSString *)getNibName:(NSString *)strNibName
    {
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            return strNibName;
        else
            NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_iphone",strNibName]);
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_iphone",strNibName];
    }
```

and call this when ever you required

```
    ViewController *obj=[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:[AppDelegate getNibName:@"ViewController"] bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Comment: There is not need to do this, iOS can do this for you by using the platform specifier in the name like `~ipad` or `~iphone`.

Answer (score 0):

For this very first thing that you have to check is file owner in your iPad xib should same controller as that of iPhone xib. Then make all the connection as you made in the iPhone xib components then this should work.

Comment: I gave the class name as ViewController of file owner.but my app is crashing when i run in the ipad

Comment: can you please put crash log